# Not able to checked all rows of datagrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

We have datagrid in which we are listing products with checkboxs in in its first column. Checkbox is used to select products in grid. There is also a checkbox in header title of datagrid.

Now, we want that, if we check checkbox in header title, then system checked all the products in datagrid.

Following is the code, we have used:

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{endListingArr}" x="20" y="61" height="100%" width="100%" id="product_end_list_grid" creationComplete="end_list_grid_reference(event)">
<s:columns>
 <s:ArrayList>
   <s:GridColumn dataField="" headerText="" width="50" headerRenderer="com.pims.renderers.ebay_end_list_header_checkbox" sortable="false">                                                
   <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
      <s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
        <fx:Script>  
          <![CDATA[
              import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
              [Bindable] private var showCheckbox:Boolean = true;

               private function changeSelection(item:Object):void{
                   item.selected = !item.selected
                   if(item.selected == false){
                     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.isEbayEndListHeaderChecked = false;
                   }
               }                                                                 
          ]]>
       </fx:Script>                                                           
       <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="18" visible="{showCheckbox}" includeInLayout="{showCheckbox}">
         <s:CheckBox selected="{data.selected}" click="changeSelection(data)" />
       </s:HGroup>                                                  
    </s:GridItemRenderer>                                           
   </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
  </s:GridColumn>
  <s:GridColumn dataField="sku" headerText="SKU" />
  <s:GridColumn dataField="product_name" headerText="Product Name" />
  <s:GridColumn dataField="ebay_item_id" headerText="Ebay online Id"/>
  <s:GridColumn dataField="store_name" headerText="Store"/>
  <s:GridColumn dataField="end_date" headerText="End Time"/>
  <s:GridColumn dataField="status" headerText="End Status"/>                                         
 </s:ArrayList>
 </s:columns>
 </s:DataGrid>
```

Header checkbox renderer(ebay_end_list_header_checkbox.mxml):

```
<s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"                        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">  
<fx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
   import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

   private var item:Object;
   protected function hcb_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
     var products:ArrayCollection = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.ebay_end_list_data_grid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
     if(CheckBox(event.currentTarget).selected){
        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.isEbayEndListHeaderChecked = true;
        for each(item in products){
    item.selected = true;
    }
}else{                       
        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.isEbayEndListHeaderChecked = false;
    for each(item in products){
    item.selected = false;
    }
}
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.ebay_end_list_data_grid.dataProvider = products;
products.refresh();
  }
 ]]>
 </fx:Script>
 <s:HGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="3">
   <s:CheckBox id="hcb" click="hcb_clickHandler(event)" selected="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.isEbayEndListHeaderChecked}"/>       
 </s:HGroup>
 </s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer>
```

Following is the srceen shot of datagrid before checking header checkbox:
    [image]

Now,when we checked checkbox in title bar, then system is skipping few rows to check as given below screen shot:

[image]

Can anyone please tell us, what is wrong with code? Why is skipping few rows to check??

Waiting for solution.

Comment: Have You debug Your Code?

Comment: Yes, we have also debug our code. Internally, when we check the checkbox in header, then system set selected variable value as true for all datagrid rows. But now showing checked for few rows.

Comment: I think checkbox values are internally updated, but the display is not updated. In your column itemrenderer override the updateDisplaylist method and in that method set the checkbox.selected = data.selected

Comment: Thanks. We have override the mention function but its giving error as "Method marked override must override another method". Can you please share how the updateDisplayList method will be override?

Comment: try to call `invalidatedisplaylist` and `validatenow` on the datagrid!

Answer (score 0):

try putting this code inside your s:GridItemRenderer  script
after giving an id to your checkBox (for example 'chk')

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void{
     super.data = value;
     try{
           chk.selected = data.selected == true ? true : false
     }
     catch(e:error){}

     }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a better approach?

from your custom HeaderRenderer, when the user clicks on the checkbox, dispatch a custom event that contains the boolean flag (checked or unchecked). lets call it checkBoxEvent

from your datagrid's container, provide an event listener to handle checkboxEvent. your event handler would then update your model. lets call it model myModel. here is an example code:

```
for each(var item:MyVO in myModel.listOfThings)  {
    item.selected = checkBoxEvent.selected;
}
myModel.listOfThings.refresh();
```

Make sure your model is bindable and have overriden "set data()" in your check box item renderers.

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void{
     super.data = value;
     if (data) {
         checkbox.selected = data.selected;   // data.selected is boolean
     }
}
```

I think the use of FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is abused here.